# How to access foreground service from WebView Javascript Bridge

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I will try and explain everything to the best of my ability, but I am new to using Xamarin so please bear with me while I try to give you an understanding of my situation.

I am using Xamarin Forms to build an Android application, I already have a desktop application that uses Electron so I have lots of pre-built user interface in HTML which I am using in a HybridWebView for the interface and JSBridge to call the C# code.

My application will only be installed on a clients network of devices, and we have set up a foreground service, that has a service notification to keep the background jobs running; this is all working as intended.

Calling C# code from the HTML interface is easy enough using the JSBridge / HybridWebView, however, I am unable to find a way that allows my C# functions inside the JSBridge class to talk to my foreground service which has already been started by the MainActivity, this service runs background jobs that return data that my UI will need access to.

My Service is being started in the MainActivity OnCreate like so:

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationService));
StartService(startServiceIntent);
```

The service is quite basic and is like this

```
[Service]
public class NotificationService : Service
{

   public int SomeDataFromBackgroundJob { get; set; }

   public override void OnCreate()
   {
      base.OnCreate();
   }

   public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
   {
      RegisterForegroundService();
      // This tells Android not to restart the service if it is killed to reclaim resources.
      return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
   }

   public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
   {
      return null;
   }

   public override void OnDestroy()
   {
      //Destroy background jobs
      base.OnDestroy();
   }

   void RegisterForegroundService()
   {
      // Enlist this instance of the service as a foreground service
      StartForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_UNIQUE_APP_ID, BuildNotification());
   }        

   Notification BuildNotification()
   {
      if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
      {
         var channel = new NotificationChannel(Constants.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_CHANNEL_ID, Constants.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationImportance.Min);
         channel.LightColor = Color.Blue;
         channel.EnableVibration(false);
         channel.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Secret;
         var service = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

         service.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
      }

      var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_CHANNEL_ID);
      var notification = notificationBuilder.SetOngoing(true)
         .SetContentTitle($"Tap to see account status: {number}")
         .SetContentIntent(BuildIntentToShowMainActivity())
         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon) //Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_name)
         .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Min)
         .SetCategory(Notification.CategoryService)
         .Build();

      return notification;
   }
   //Sniped background job code
}
```

My JSBridge code is:

```
public class JSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
{
    readonly WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer> hybridWebViewRenderer;

    public JSBridge(HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer)
    {
        hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer>(hybridRenderer);
    }

    [JavascriptInterface]
    [Export("IsUserLoggedIn")]
    public string IsUserLoggedIn()
    {
        //WebView.Uri = "login.html";
        //This returns a null object for the service, because its a "normal foreground service, not a dependancy"
        if (DependencyService.Get<NotificationService>().SomeDataFromBackgroundJob == 3)
        {
            //Got data from background job
            return "Something to return to the UI/JS";
        }

        return null;
    }

    public HybridWebView WebView
    {
        get
        {
            HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer;

            if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget(out hybridRenderer))
            {
                return ((HybridWebView)hybridRenderer.Element);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see inside IsUserLoggedIn (an example function I made) I tried to use DependencyService.Get but it returns a null object. It's important that my IsUserLoggedIn has access to the same instance of the NotificationService that my MainActivity started because the background jobs are business-critical and take a long time to run on most devices.

I think this should be a pretty normal use case(especially if you ignore the fact I'm using the HTML UI), and I'm sure there must be a way to do this.

Any advice and input would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a "Bound Service" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/bound-services

Comment: @SushiHangover I don't think that possible with a foreground service?

Comment: You can create a binder for any type of Android Service. Being a "foreground" service does not change the fact that it is a Service subclass, it tells the OS how to handle its lifecycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by SushiHangover, using a bound service is the way to go.

The documentation isn't very helpful and while it says a bound service calls OnBind() to start, it also mentions that it can also call OnStartCommand. However, the documentation doesn't mention that to have OnStartCommand fire you need to call StartService as well as BindService.

Example:

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationService));
BindService(startServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
StartService(startServiceIntent);
```